# Populate spinner with custom object

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to populate my Android spinner with data from a SQLite table. 
I already have the database controllers, and these are returning custom objects.

Now what I need to do is populate the spinner with this objects, in order to get not the string field, but the Id field. For example:
My table Days, with fields Id and Day:

id - day
1  - Sunday

2  - Monday

3  - Tuesday...

And the Day object has two properties (id, and name)

I want the spinner to show "Monday", but internally, store the Id field '2' in an int variable, in order to query again the database with theese selected values.

I think I have to do it with an Adapter, but I don't know if I can do what I want with this controller.

I'd apreciate some order or advice to begin with.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ArrayAdapter<T>` to populate your spinner via the method `setAdapter`.

```
private List<MyData> data;
...
mySpinner.setAdapter<MyData>(new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), resId, data));
...

public class MyData {

     private int _id;
     public MyData(int id) {
         this._id = id;
     }

  @Override 
  public String toString() {
     switch (this._id) {
       ....
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do so with Custom Spinner. See [this](http://mrbool.com/how-to-customize-spinner-in-android/28286) Design the spinner item separately in xml and use LayoutInflator.

Answer (score 1):

save:
In the getView() of your Adapter use "setTag" method set the "Day object"

retrive:(onItemSelcted method of spinner)
now by using getTag() method, get the "Day object" (Day object.getId() will return the int value)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved it following this tutorial.

http://adanware.blogspot.com.es/2012/03/android-using-spinner-with-custom.html